# Why clojure.repl/source does not works for my custom functtion

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

When I execute the `clojure.repl/source activate` in repl, it gives me the source of the activate function.

Now, I defined a custom function in namespace `tutorial.test`

```
(ns tutorial.test)
    (defn return_type_of_arg
        [x]
        (type x)
)
```

After switching the repl namespace to `tutorial.test` and loading this file in repl, I tried to execute `clojure.repl/source return_type_of_arg`.

It's giving me the output as `Source not found`

What's going wrong?

**EDITS:**

I have confirmed that the namespace is shifted to the one required. Please see the following image:

[image]

**These are the exact steps I followed:**

1. Created a file `test.clj` and added above fucntion into it.
2. Left clicked this file in Intellij Idea and selected option `Switch REPL namespace to current file`.
3. Left clicked this file in Intellij Idea and selected option
   `Load file in REPL`.

Comment: You can try *ns* to see if you have really shifted to the namespace you mentioned. It is likely that the function you defined isn't loaded properly? + are you running those commands right from the prompt? (without helps from ides like intellij, vscode, and emacs)

Comment: It will be helpful if you can show a transcript of what you typed at the REPL. The `Source not found` error indicates that `clojure.repl/source` was not able to find the source code for the argument provided.  Which further indicates that you are not in the namespace that you expected.

Comment: Folks, I have added the screenshot

Comment: From the screenshot, I am unable to determine what ns you are in.  Try typing `*ns*` at the REPL and see what it says.  Also, looking at the code in the screenshot, `def`s should typically be at the top level, not within the scope of a `defn`.

Comment: Added a new screenshot @dorab

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe the function is not properly loaded into the namespace then.  Try typing `return_type_of_arg` at the REPL.

Comment: When I typed `return_type_of_arg` in REPL, it returned - `#object[tutorial.test$return_type_of_arg 0x1bf04b67 "tutorial.test$return_type_of_arg@1bf04b67"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a transcript of a REPL session that shows the steps to make this work.

```
dorabs-imac:tmp dorab$ cat tutorial.clj
(ns tutorial)

(defn return_type_of_arg
  [x]
  (type x))
dorabs-imac:tmp dorab$ clj -Sdeps '{:paths ["."]}'
Clojure 1.10.3
user=> (require 'tutorial)
nil
user=> (in-ns 'tutorial)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x187eb9a8 "tutorial"]
tutorial=> (clojure.repl/source return_type_of_arg)
(defn return_type_of_arg
  [x]
  (type x))
nil
tutorial=> 

dorabs-imac:tmp dorab$
```

**Added in edit:**

1. First I created a file called `tutorial.clj` with the `ns` form and the `defn` of the function.
2. Then I started a REPL with the current directory (`.`) in the CLASSPATH so Clojure knows where to load the file from.
3. Then I loaded up the file using `require`.  This loads the function definition into the `tutorial` namespace.
4. Then I changed the current namespace of the REPL to be `tutorial` using the `in-ns` function.
5. Then I ran the `clojure.repl/source` function.

**Further edit:**

I *think* I have identified the problem you are facing.  It seems that the way you are using IntelliJ, it is sending the contents of the file to the REPL, rather than `require`ing the file.  According to the docs for `source`, "Prints the source code for the given symbol, if it can find it.
**This requires that the symbol resolve to a Var defined in a
namespace for which the .clj is in the classpath**." [Emphasis mine].  So, when the file contents are sent to the REPL directly (without using `require`) there is no `.clj` file for `source` to look for the source.  The following transcript demonstrates that.  Compare the following transcript with the transcript above that does work.

```
dorabs-imac:tmp dorab$ clj
Clojure 1.10.3
user=> (ns tutorial)

(defn return_type_of_arg
  [x]
  (type x))

nil
tutorial=> tutorial=> #'tutorial/return_type_of_arg
tutorial=> tutorial=> (clojure.repl/source return_type_of_arg)
Source not found
nil
tutorial=>
```

Comment: Please sir can you explain what was the issue and what you did step by step as I am new to Clojure @dorab

Comment: I don't know the exact issue for you unless you tell us the exact steps you took.  I have edited my answer to specify the steps I took and the explanations.

Comment: I have added the exact steps

Comment: I am not familiar enough with IntelliJ.  Can you try swapping your steps 2 and 3?

Comment: Swapped steps 2 and 3-> Not working. I will try to follow your answer

Comment: The docstring for `source` says "Prints the source code for the given symbol, if it can find it.
This requires that the symbol resolve to a Var defined in a
namespace **for which the .clj is in the classpath**." [Emphasis mine].  Maybe, the way IntelliJ works, the file is not in the classpath?

Comment: I just have one word - Excellent !